# Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite from localhost

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I would like to rewrite the URL in a reverse proxy so in my case I would like to change url like below, I ran some containers so they callable now but with port and localhost I add a new container with nginx revers proxy and with this I would like to revert my url but I don't know how should I define nginx.conf in this path /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
when I enter some url it should call like below:

http://addons.example.com  => http://localhost:89
http://my.example.com => http://localhost
http://phpmyadmin.example.com => http://localhost:5054
```

due to my config I got this error in docker log when I call http://addons.project.com/test.php:
`production_nginx        | 2022/02/23 13:49:27 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/test.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.25.0.1, server: my.project.com, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", host: "addons.project.com"`

this is my config of nginx:

```
events {

}

http {
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

  server {
    server_name my.example.com;

    location /my.example.com/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
      rewrite ^/my.example.com(.*)$ $1;
    }

    location /addons.example.com/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:89;
      rewrite ^/addons.example.com(.*)$ $1;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for virtual host setups, not `location` blocks in a single `server` block.

Your current setup corresponds to following URLs:

```
https://my.example.com/my.example.com -> 127.0.0.1:80
https://my.example.com/addons.example.com -> 127.0.0.1:89
```

You likely want separate `server` blocks:

```
server {
    server_name my.example.com;

    proxy_pass http://localhost;
}

server {
    server_name addons.example.com;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:89;
}

server {
    server_name phpmyadmin.example.com;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:5054;
}
```

You might need the `rewrite` statements if you cannot configure your applications base URL properly.